# Imports error BC40056 after update to VS 2019

Tags: vb.net

After updating to VS 2019 (Community), in one of my projects an `Imports` statement throws a warning (and with that a lot of errors, of course) when I compile the solution:

> **Warning BC40056** Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'mysolution.DataLayer' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found. Make sure the namespace or the type is defined and contains at least one public member. Make sure the imported element name doesn't use any aliases.

('mysolution.DataLayer' is a DLL I wrote as part of the solution.)

When opening the same solution in VS 2017 (Community) there is no problem.

I import as usual, among other DLLs that don't make that problem:

```vb
Imports mysolution.DataLayer
```

In the Solution Explorer I can see "mysolution.DataLayer" under "References". When I open menu "Project | mysolution Properties ..." I see it also in the "References" list (but not under "Imported namespaces"). I can compile it in VS 2017, but as soon as I go back to 2019 and try to compile, the errors reappear.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to remove and re-add the reference?

Comment: Yes, I tried that. The error remains.

Comment: "'mysolution.DataLayer' is a DLL I wrote as part of the solution." - Give this a try. In the Solution Explorer window, right click on the mysolution.DataLayer project and select rebuild.  i.e. just rebuild that project, not the entire solution.

Comment: Sounds like a regression of [this bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/160241/errors-reported-when-none-exist.html).

Comment: Tried a lot of different things, among others re-added the reference to "DataLayer" once more, disabled "allow parallel project initialization" (from your tip @Hans Passant; upvoted you for this), rebuild "DataLayer" and other things. At some point the errors were gone, can't say what did the trick, though. Maybe I was a little hectic. Thanks for all tips. After it works now I my solution didn't load after restart. I got a message that VS 2019 is sending an error report to MS. If I deinstall the extension "CodeMaid" everything works. That's sad because I used CodeMaid a lot. :o(